# Calling SysV msgsnd from signal handler

Tags: linux, signals, ipc

Is it safe to invoke `msgsnd` function from signal handler?

Code for our services is not intended to every gracefully complete, so I don't have exit point, however I need to send message to another process when services is stopped, so I need to catch SIGTERM and perform `msgsnd` before calling exit(0).

Is that safe?

I looked into [signal safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) manual page and did not found `msgsnd` in the list. Should I consider this as unsafe function? What are the possible consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not safe.  (Note that `exit()` doesn't appear on [the async-signal-safe function list](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03), either, though `_exit()` does.)

`msgsnd` might silently fail, might error out, might segfault, might hang forever, etc.

Consider refactoring a bit — if you need to do something upon SIGTERM then I'd say you *do* need graceful, or at least not clumsy, shutdown logic.  If that's not feasible, perhaps [`SEM_UNDO`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semop.html) can do what you want, as you seem to be comfortable with SysV IPC already.  Or hold a file-system lock that is released upon process death.  Or have the service parent catch SIGCHLD and then call `msgsnd`.  Etc.

Comment: That's backup plan, but this will require lots of refactoring.

Comment: anyway, that's answers my question. Thanks a lot!